# Bluetooth headphones problem on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: bluetooth, 19.10, headphones

I have a [wireless bluetooth headphones P47](https://fr.gearbest.com/bluetooth-headphones/pp_1180988.html) and [bluetooth 2.0 usb dongle](https://www.amazon.in/SmartPro-Bluetooth-USB-Dongle-Mini/dp/B00INVZK9E) and i tried several times to connect my wireless headphones to my PC with Ubuntu 19.10 but it didn't work and [connexion toggle is greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHmbB.png) and i can't enable it.

I think my wireless headphones bluetooth version is v4.2, i am wondering if my bluetooth 2.0 dongle is compatible with it or i should by a 4.2 bluetooth dongle.

Comment: Have you confirmed that this dongle works with these headphones on another system? Have you confirmed that the headphones work with other bluetooth devices? Have you tested to see if there are drivers installed for the dongle? WIth the information you have currently provided, it is difficult to discern if this is an issue with Ubuntu or not

Comment: I didn't test my headphones on other system yet (i have only Ubuntu for now) but it works just fine with my smartphone, and the bluetooth dongle works fine when i try to connect my smartphone to my pc so there is just my headphones that can't be connected to my pc.